# Linq: SqlFunctions.PatIndex vs string.Contains for string comparisson

Tags: c#, linq

Which of the following versions for the same query will perform better:

**Version 1 (string.Contains):**

```
var query = db.Products
    .Where( p => p.Description.Contains( description ) );
```

**Version 2 ( SqlFunctions.PatIndex ):**

```
var query = db.Products
    .Where( p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + description + "%",p.Description) > 0  );
```

Comment: Just time both the versions with `Stopwatch` and see which one is faster.

Comment: Actually your question is not relevant to linq - its about performance of `PATINDEX` vs `LIKE`

Comment: @SonerGönül, i did that before ask and the results were irrelevant. I post the question hoping that someone that had dealed with large data express his experiences in that matter.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it is relevant to linq from my point of view because sql is going to be generated from linq code not raw sql.

Comment: @Elio.Batista SQL generation is very fast comparing to data retrieving from database server. Also I have doubts if any of these two approaches will be generated several ticks faster than other. So, real difference is in executing generated plain SQL query on server side

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I will take your suggestion into accout. I will keep this open to see if other people can collaborate too. I'm building the infrastructure of a very large system (ERP) so is very important for me to clarify thinks like this before go into deeper development. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe version 1 runs faster theoretically.

Reasons:

1. Both versions translate into SQL queries eventually.
2. Version 1 translates into a query with where clause having 'like' operator
3. Version 2 translate into a query with where clause having 'PatIndex' function.
4. We know function in SQL will take longer time to return results when comparing with pure 'like' operator in large data set.