# Linq Query Where() SQL % equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We can use the method `.Contains(string)` in a LINQ Expression, that sounds like '%search text%', method `.StartsWith(string)`, that sounds like 'search text%', and method `.EndsWith(string)`, that sounds like '%search text'.

But I need something that sounds '%search%text%', that finds all content containing 'search' and 'text', but not sequential.

Example: I have these records:

> search my text
>
> search for the text
>
> seek the text

In SQL, the query with `LIKE '%search%text%'` brings:

> **search** my **text**
>
> **search** for the **text**

But not brings the `'seek the text'`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use regular expressions: replace `%` with `.*` and `_` with `.`

Comment: Does this works? `.Contains("search").Contains("text")` there may be some syntax errors in my code, but I hope you get my idea.

Comment: Are you using LINQ on objects, or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: If you use SQL Server, you can use `Patindex` from `SqlFunctions`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22455782/2387977 . But, I'm have your doubt too.

Comment: @zerkms, how we can use regular expressions in a Linq Expression query?

Comment: @Turtle I need it dinamically. Imagine something that sounds 'search%text' and '%search%the%text%'. I don't know what I will get. I need to find addresses in a table. Blorgbeard, I'm using LINQ-to-SQL

Answer (score 7):

You can use one of the helper method:

```
var result = from o in ctx.table
where SqlMethods.Like(o.column, "%search%text%")
select o.column;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
var rx = new Regex("search.*text", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List<string> lists=new List<string>(){"search text","search this text","search my book"};
var result = lists.Where(x => rx.IsMatch(x));
```

> If you getting input in the form of "search%text", then you could just string replace "%" with ".*" and use as Reg ex pattern.

Comment: You could not use regex with linq to sql. You will need first select all data in memory and then filter with regex, which is inefficient comparing to like function which will filter data on sql layer and return already filtered data.

Comment: What do you mean ? I could easily do: `from x in lists where rx.IsMatch(x) select x;` , If you are saying about the filtering in case of linq to sql , then ,yes, you are right, the code does filter in memory vs filtering in sql server itself, however there is different overhead to using linq to sql.

Comment: I mean if you have billion rows and want to filter only 10 rows you will need to load those billion rows to memory first which is a big overhead

Comment: Yes, but I'm not talking about billion rows, I'm not talking about big data either. Everything depends upon your requirement. And nothing fits best in all the situation. If you are talking about facebook database, yes, billion rows! and your code works best! but, I'm simply giving an option when you are not using linq to sql, just list of strings.